# Split line at commas, only if commas not contained between quotes

Tags: regex, scala

Is there any way to use the `split` function in scala so that it splits a line at commas but doesn't at commas contained within 2 double quotes?

For example, I have the following:

```
x: String = """"??", "hamburger", "ketchup, mayo, mustard", "pizza""""
```

and I tried this:
`x.split(',')` but it didn't work. I then thought about removing all double quotes but that still doesn't solve my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's a snippet of my code to see how I can incorporate this:

```
val data1 = noheader1.map { line =>
  val values = line._1.split(',') //This is what I am trying to change
  val name = values(2).replaceAll("\"", ""))
```

I am a bit new to scala and even more so to regex, so could someone clarify how to write that weird regex expression in my code so that I can obtain an ARRAY of the comma separated words of the line?

Comment: I'll recommend you to parse the line as a CSV that is delimited by comma!

Comment: Just to be clear: with a CSV parser, as @SabujHassan suggested, the commas won't be a problem if the parser respects [RFC4180, especially Section 2.6](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the tips. To Mike, x comes from the line of an RDD that I parsed from a huge dataset and some values were in Japanese so they are showing up as ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this!

```
(?>"(?>\\.|[^"])*?"|(,))
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xW7iS1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of split() you can use a regular expression and findAllIn(), like such:

```
 val x = """"??", "hamburger", "ketchup, mayo, mustard", "pizza""""
 """"[^"]+"""".r.findAllIn(x).toList
```

This will result in, List("??", "hamburger", "ketchup, mayo, mustard", "pizza")

*Note: I am using triple-quotes (""") in the example.*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not so elegant as other regex already suggested, consider the splitting element between items as `", "`  and so

```
x.split("\",\\s+\"")
Array("??, hamburger, ketchup, mayo, mustard, pizza")
```

Then in the resulting array, to the `head` `"??` apply `stripPrefix("\"")` and to the `last` `pizza"` apply `stripSuffix("\"")`.